# TypeError: venuesDates.map is not a function React

Tags: reactjs, rest

I'm trying to render the Tab element from Material UI. It works the first time but if I go back to another screen and comes back it gives me the following error. It gives me headaches now I'm very new to React.

**TypeError: venuesDates.map is not a function**

[image: Error screenshot]

[image: working at first compile]

*following is my code*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState }from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import PhoneIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Phone";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import PersonPinIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PersonPin";
import HelpIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Help";
import ShoppingBasket from "@material-ui/icons/ShoppingBasket";
import ThumbDown from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbDown";
import ThumbUp from "@material-ui/icons/ThumbUp";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { DateRangeSharp } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { List, ListItem, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";

const DATES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    day: "WED",
    date: 19,
    theater: [{ tname: "vista", price: 450 }, { tname: "liberty", price: 550 }]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    day: "THU",
    date: 20,
    theater: [{ tname: "PVR" }, { tname: "CCC" }]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    day: "FRI",
    date: 21,
    theater: [{ tname: "vista" }, { tname: "liberty" }]
  },
  { id: 4, day: "SAT", date: 22 },
  { id: 5, day: "SUN", date: 23 },
  { id: 6, day: "MON", date: 24, theater: [{ tname: "vista" }, { tname: "liberty" }] },
  { id: 7, day: "TUE", date: 25 },
  { id: 8, day: "WED", date: 26 }
];

const showDatesNtimes = []

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-force-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-force-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `scrollable-force-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));

export default function ScrollableTabsButtonForce() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue ] = React.useState(0);
  const [venuesDates, setvenuesDates] = React.useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "http://sandbox-api.tickets.lk/v1/movie/3232/showtime";
    const requestOptions = (token) => {
      return ({
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'client_token': 'ebd86470-7e90-4ece-9e89-1b6d4d2cbb61' }
      })
    };
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions());
        const json = await response.json();
        // console.log(json);
        // console.log(json.data.venueDateShowtime)
        setvenuesDates(json.data.venueDateShowtime);
      }
      catch (error) {
        console.log("error",error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  })

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar
        position="static"
        style={{ background: "#333545", minHeight: 60 }}
      >
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="on"
          indicatorColor="secondary"
          textColor="primary"
          aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
          style={{ minHeight: 60 }}
          wrapped
        >
          {venuesDates.map((showtdates) => {
            return (
              <Tab
                label={showtdates.date}
                {...a11yProps(0)}
                style={{ color: "#fff", fontSize: 20, minHeight: 60 }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {/* map over dates and create TabPanel */}
{/* // check if theater property exists and create a list of theaters as an example */}
      {venuesDates.map((date, idx) => {
        
        const venues = date.hasOwnProperty("venues")
          ? date.venues.map((venues) => (
              <ListItem>
                <ListItemText
                  primary={venues.venue}
                  secondary={venues.venueId}
                />
              </ListItem>
            ))
          : null;

        return (
          <TabPanel value={value} index={idx}>
            <List>{venues}</List>
          </TabPanel>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hoping for any suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `venuesDates` as an array, it's important you initialize it as an array.
Try this

```
const [venuesDates, setvenuesDates] = React.useState([]);
```

Comment: Can you please check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68524744/data-duplicated-when-render-from-api-material-ui-tabs-react